# mozilla border gradient equivalent

Tags: html, css, firefox

I made this idea of mine to work in Chrome but still failed to do so in Firefox.
Here is the concept that works in Chrome:

```
<ul>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>

ul{-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF9999), color-stop(100%, #4AC0F2)) 0 100% 0 0/0 5px 0 0 stretch;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VCMqp/)

I tried to do as it follows to make it cool with Firefox but I get horizontal instead of vertical gradient.

```
border-right: 5px solid; -moz-border-right-colors: #71637D #FF9999;
```

Thank you

Comment: I have already been there my friend... have you?

Answer (score -1):

```
-moz-border-bottom-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-top-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-left-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-right-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
```

Change the colours to suit your needs.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, like i said i need gradient to be from top to bottom. take time and consider looking jsfiddle that i have setup for you.